# Fitting a polynomial regression model selected by `leaps::regsubsets`

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, polynomials

I have performed best subset selection of linear regression model using `leaps::regsubsets`. Then I chose the model with 14 predictors and using `coef(model, 14)` gave me the following output:

```
structure(c(16.1303774392893, -0.0787496652705482, -0.104929454314886, 
-1.22322411065346, 1.14718778105312, 0.75468065020279, 0.455617836039703, 
0.521951041899427, 0.0124590834643436, -0.0002293804247409, 
1.26667965342874e-07, 1.4002805624594e-06, -9.90560347112683e-07, 
1.8809273394337e-06, 5.48249071436573e-07), .Names = c("(Intercept)", "X1", 
"X2", "poly(X4, 2)1", "poly(X5, 2)1", "poly(X6, 2)2", "poly(X7, 2)2", 
"poly(X9, 2)1", "X10", "X12", "X13", "X14", "X16", "X17", "X18"))
```

To get this model, I need to fit it with `lm`. As `poly(X, 2)1` is linear and `poly(X, 2)2` is quadratic, I did:

```
lm(X20 ~ X1 + X2 + X4 + X5 + I(X6 ^ 2) + I(X7 ^ 2) +
         X9 + X10 + X12 + X13 + X14 + X16 + X17 + X18, df)
```

I think I know why coefficients are different (see [poly() in lm(): difference between raw vs. orthogonal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999900/poly-in-lm-difference-between-raw-vs-orthogonal)), but why don't they give the same fitted values and adjusted R2?

Of course, using `poly(X, 2)[,2]` in the formula gives complete consistency with `regsubsets` output. But is it valid to use only second term orthogonal polynomial and specify the model as follows?

```
lm(X20 ~ X1 + X2 + X4 + X5 + poly(X6, 2)[,2] + poly(X7, 2)[,2] +
   X9 + X10 + X12 + X13 + X14 + X16 + X17 + X18, df)
```

Is there more direct way to retrieve single model from `regsubsets` output than specifying the model by hand?

Comment: I have added some questions that are uncovered in attached link. I don't think it is a duplicate anymore. If the fitted values from both 'raw' and 'orthogonal' models should be the same then why adjusted R2 is different? Is the lattest `lm` formula valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but why don't they give the same fitted values and adjusted R2?

Fitted values won't necessarily be the same, if you don't use all columns from `poly`.

```
set.seed(0)
y <- runif(100)
x <- runif(100)
X <- poly(x, 3)

all.equal(lm(y ~ X)$fitted, lm(y ~ x + I(x ^ 2) + I(x ^ 3))$fitted)
#[1] TRUE

all.equal(lm(y ~ X[, 1:2])$fitted, lm(y ~ x + I(x ^ 2))$fitted)
#[1] TRUE

all.equal(lm(y ~ X - 1)$fitted, lm(y ~ x + I(x ^ 2) + I(x ^ 3) - 1)$fitted)  ## no intercept
#[1] "Mean relative difference: 33.023"

all.equal(lm(y ~ X[, c(1, 3)])$fitted, lm(y ~ x + I(x ^ 3))$fitted)
#[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.03008166"

all.equal(lm(y ~ X[, c(2, 3)])$fitted, lm(y ~ I(x ^ 2) + I(x ^ 3))$fitted)
#[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.03297488"
```

We only have `~ 1 + poly(x, degree)[, 1:k]` equivalent to `~ 1 + x + I(x ^ 2) + ... + I(x ^ k)`, for any `k <= degree`. (I explicitly write out the intercept, to emphasize that we have to start from polynomial of degree 0.)

(*The reason is related to how an orthogonal polynomial is generated. See [How `poly()` generates orthogonal polynomials? How to understand the "coefs" returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39031172/how-poly-generates-orthogonal-polynomials-how-to-understand-the-coefs-ret/39051154#39051154) for great great details. Note that when doing a QR factorization `X = QR`, as `R` is an upper triangular matrix (not a diagonal matrix), `Q[, ind]` will not have the same column space with `X[, ind]` for an arbitrary subset `ind`, unless `ind = 1:k`.*)

So, `I(x ^ 2)` is not equivalent to `ploy(x, 2)[, 2]`, and you will get different fitted values hence (adjusted) R2.

> is it valid to use only second term orthogonal polynomial and specify the model as follows?

It is really a bad idea for `leaps` (or generally any modeler) to drop columns from an orthogonal polynomial. An orthogonal polynomial is a factor-alike term, whose significance is determined by F-statistics (i.e., treating all columns as a whole), rather than t-statistics for individual columns.

In fact, even for raw polynomials, it is not a good idea to omit any low order term. For example, `y ~ 1 + I(x ^ 2)` omitting linear term is not a good idea. A basic problem here is that it is not invariant to linear shift. For example, if we shift `x` for `x1`:

```
shift <- runif(1)  ## an arbitrary value; can be `mean(x)`
x1 <- x - shift
```

then `y ~ 1 + I(x ^ 2)` is not equivalent to `y ~ 1 + I(x1 ^ 2)`, but still, `y ~ 1 + x + I(x ^ 2)` is equivalent to `y ~ 1 + x1 + I(x1 ^ 2)`.

```
all.equal(lm(y ~ 1 + I(x ^ 2))$fitted, lm(y ~ 1 + I(x1 ^ 2))$fitted)
#[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.02020984"

all.equal(lm(y ~ 1 + x + I(x ^ 2))$fitted, lm(y ~ 1 + x1 + I(x1 ^ 2))$fitted)
#[1] TRUE
```

I briefly mentioned the issue of dropping columns at [R: How to or should I drop an insignificant orthogonal polynomial basis in a linear model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019251/r-how-to-or-should-i-drop-an-insignificant-orthogonal-polynomial-basis-in-a-lin?rq=1), but my examples here give you more insight.

> Is there more direct way to retrieve single model from `regsubsets` output than specifying the model by hand?

I don't know; at least I did not figure it out almost 2 years ago when answering this thread: [Get all models from leaps regsubsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000835/get-all-models-from-leaps-regsubsets?rq=1).

---

> One remaining question though. Assuming that `leaps` returns `poly(X, 2)1` I should definitely retain `poly(X, 2)1` in my model. But what if only `poly(X, 2)1` is returned by `leaps`? Can higher order term can be dropped then?

There is no problem dropping higher order terms (in this case where you originally fitted a quadratic polynomial). As I said, we have equivalence for `ind = 1:j`, where `j <= degree`. But make sure you understand this. Take the following two examples.

- **If `leaps` drops `poly(x, 5)3` and `poly(x, 5)5`.** you can safely remove `poly(x, 5)5`, but are still advised to retain `poly(x, 5)3`. This is, instead of fitting an 5-th order polynomial, you fit a 4-th order one.
- **If `leaps` drops `poly(x, 6)3` and `poly(x, 6)5`**. Since `poly(x, 6)6` is not dropped, you are advised to drop no terms at all.

Comment: Wow, it is very insightful. One remaining question though. Assuming that `leaps` returns `poly(X, 2)1` I should remain `poly(X, 2)1` in a model as well, that's clear. But what if only `poly(X, 2)1` is returned by `leaps`? Can higher order term can be dropped then?